# Display content based on group membership - OKTA + ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, okta, okta-api

I'm using Okta for user authentication of my SPA (+ Express backend).
How can I use the Okta API to show/hide content based on group membership?

e.g. if I want to show some menu items if the active user is a member of a specific group.

Is there anything in the Okta React SDK?
I'm coming up short, product seems great, docs seems less so.

I've found this API https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#get-member-groups

I'm however unsure of how to best use this from my app. when and where should I call it, should I store group membership in some object and then pass that to all my sub components?

Any ideas and directions are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying the `groups` scope, you can return a list of active `groups` the user is assigned to. In your React app, use [`@okta/okta-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-react) to overload the default params by passing the following into `Security`:

```
<Security issuer={config.issuer}
          client_id={config.client_id}
          redirect_uri={window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback'}
          scope={['openid', 'email', 'profile', 'groups']}
          onAuthRequired={({history}) => history.push('/login')} >
```

*Sample code taken from the [React Quickstart](https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/react/nodejs/generic).*

Next, use the `getUser()` method to return the full user object from the `userInfo` API.

```
this.props.auth.getUser().then(profile => {
  const groups = profile.groups;
  // Do your show/hide logic here
});
```

> This requires extra configuration in your Okta OpenID Connect app to accept `groups` as a scope. More info on that [here (Creating Token with Groups)](https://developer.okta.com/docs/how-to/creating-token-with-groups-claim.html) and [here (Okta Answers)](https://support.okta.com/help/answers?id=9062A000000bmOuQAI).