# Okta - React SDK - Get user groups

Tags: reactjs, okta

I want to get the groups the user belongs to. I follow this topic:
[Display content based on group membership - OKTA + ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611058/display-content-based-on-group-membership-okta-reactjs)

I added the scope to the ReactJS Security component, and I added the scope `groups` to the default Authorization Server in OKTA. After that, following the link instructions, I also had to `Create a Groups Claim for Okta-Master groups`.

I did all this, no errors, but when I get the user object via `auth.getUser()` in React, I see the same info as before, no groups.

I know it is possible to manually query groups and group-memberships via the OKTA API, but it would be nice if I could do it this way.

Any ideas?

React Component:

```
<Security issuer='https://<url>/oauth2/default'
  client_id='<client_id>'
  redirect_uri={window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback'}
  scope={['openid', 'email', 'profile', 'groups']}
  onAuthRequired={onAuthRequired} >
```

Default Authorization server:
[image]

Groups claim filter:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you requesting id_token and access token together? or are you using authorization code flow with gives id token and access token together?  If so, Okta returns "thin token" which only have default values. So you have to send your access token to userinfo. endpoint and get groups.

Comment: How can I see that? I will add some code to my question